# JavaScript div creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need a small hand here im trying to combine two functions to create a program that takes text from a text area and inserts it into a div (managed that with the first code) the second peace of code im trying to create a div each time, what id like to do is everytime some one writes in the textarea and "posts" the message it will create a new div (rather than the first code which overwrites if anything new is posted).

```
$(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        var x = $('textarea').val();
        $('#test').html(x);
        return false;
    });
});
```

second:

```
function creatediv(id, html, width, height, left, top) {

       var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
       newdiv.setAttribute('id', id);

       if (width) {
           newdiv.style.width = 300;
       }

       if (height) {
           newdiv.style.height = 300;
       }

       if ((left || top) || (left && top)) {
           newdiv.style.position = "absolute";

           if (left) {
               newdiv.style.left = left;
           }

           if (top) {
               newdiv.style.top = top;
           }
       }

       newdiv.style.background = "#00C";
       newdiv.style.border = "4px solid #000";

       if (html) {
           newdiv.innerHTML = html;
       } else {
           newdiv.innerHTML = "nothing";
       }

       document.body.appendChild(newdiv);

    }
```

Being careful tho as I have divs set by css for my master page in asp, dont want to overwrite them. Its important I dont add them to the same div aswell as I will be adding more code later that will contain a button inside the created div to add comments to that div only.

Thanks to any and all that can help!

Comment: Why do you want to use a createDiv method? Simply using jquery's `after()` method will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, don't bother re-inventing the wheel.  Get a library like jQuery and learn it.  Faster, easier.

http://jquery.com/

But since jquery is one of your tags, I take it that you are using it?

In that case, just use append:

http://api.jquery.com/append/

```
$(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        var x = $('textarea').val();
        $('#test').append(x);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: hey thanks yeah I tryed that not what im after tho, need it to add a new div with the text after the first div, so it looks layered on the wall post page of my site. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: $('#test').append("<div class='whatever'>" + x + "</div>");

Answer (score 1):

Basically it would be:

```
$(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        var x = $('textarea').val();
        creatediv(..., x, ...);
        return false;
    });
});
```

However you'd need to provide the other parameters (id, width, height, left, top) of your function somehow. From your description I can't say what you would want to use there.

BTW, your `creatediv` has errors. The style properties `width`, `height`(and `left`and `top`) require units, so you have to use (for example):

```
newdiv.style.width = "300px";
```

Comment: yeah thats not dynamically creating the div, I have to set the id dont i? I need it to create its own (eachtime) atm I just need to see if its possible so any width height, left, top etc but the id must be set by the java each time there is a posting rather than me setting it as this would only duplicate the same div and i would be back at square one with duplicated divs and also text.

Comment: There is not requirement to set an ID. You could modify `creatediv` not to set it if you don't provide it.

Answer (score 1):

See the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gubhaju/WmyNY/)
I think that's what u wanted to do.

Comment: This is nice but still not what I need, I need a new div created each time some one posts text from the textarea.

Comment: @garrith see it on firebug, it creates new div each time you click the button